# Convert ConTeXt to LaTeX?

Tags: context, convert

I know [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) can convert LaTeX to ConTeXt, but what about the other way round?  I have a ConTeXt document (which I prepared myself some years ago), which I want to include in a much larger LaTeX document.  And the easiest way that I can see is to convert that ConTeXt to LaTeX.

Is there a script for this?  Or is it a matter of grinding through by hand, so to speak?

Comment: I am not aware of a converter. Depends on how complicated your code is. One option is to define LaTeX commands like `\newcommand\startwhatever{\begin{whatever}}` etc. Or you can use search and replace (or a regex based search and replace).

Comment: What I've done in the end is run `detex` on the initial ConTeXt document, and then started adding in the LaTeX commands on the resulting text.  This also allows for some cleaning up and re-editing.

Comment: Just typeset the ConTeXt document and include it via `\includepdf` from the `pdfpages` package.  That way you can be sure to not lose any formatting.

Comment: Is it worth converting via [html export](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/html-export/)? That is, put something like `\setupbackend[export=yes, xhtml=yes]` at the top, and then see what xslt shenanigans you can accomplish on the `.export` or `.xhtml` output file.

Comment: @HenriMenke That was my first thought as well. Do you want to make that an answer?